# Is a time change term (t or c squared) ALWAYS necessary to describe interactions between particles or objects?

Tags: forces, visible-light, time, relativity

Is it true that all physics equations that describe any force or interaction between anything requires the rate of time to change at the time of the force or interaction? This is mathematically seen in the form of time squared (or a time variable speed like c squared, or a force inclusive of time squared like acceleration). It seems present in everything from thermodynamics to particle entanglement collapse whenever anything reacts with anything else. Is this true or am I overlooking some interaction that happens without necessitating t2?

Comment: Not always. In quantum mechanics, wave function is the physics state, however, in Heisenberg picture, it doesn't deal with the time evolution of wavefunction.

Answer (score -1):

The time-independent Schrodinger equation describes a particle at some instance $t$ in a state given by the wavefunction $\psi$.

$$ \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2\Psi}{\mathrm{d}x^2} + U(x)\Psi(x) = E\Psi(x) $$

Comment: This answer is not clear, most importantly, you are basely just saying: okay, "let's just fix time, then it is a equation describing physics without involving time evolution." That's a tautology.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. You took time out all  together. My confusion is whether there is always a second dimension to time, t squared, involved in any 2 things interacting. i.e. If something "touches" something else, we know they have touched because their respective rates of time have changed.